# How to extract only 3 video frames at 0,5,10 seconds using FFMPEG?

Tags: ffmpeg, h.264, video-processing

Command I am using:

```
ffmpeg -i input -c:v libx264 -movflags +faststart -preset slow -crf 22 -b:v 500k -c:a libvo_aacenc -b:a 128k "out.mp4" -r 1 -t 3 -ss 3 -s sqcif "%%1d.jpg"
```

Comment: This question would have been better with more context.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the [`select`](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#select_002c-aselect) filter:

```
ffmpeg -i input.mp4 -vf "select='eq(t,0)+eq(t,5)+eq(t,10)'" -vsync vfr output_%03d.png
```

`-vsync vfr` will prevent it from outputting unwanted, duplicate frames.

Comment: Sadly, it doesn’t work in 2018, and the PTS problem seems to still be here: ffmpeg hogs all CPU cores and produces no output.

Comment: @tijagi Try the updated answer. If it doesn't work you can use a pastebin site to show your command and the complete console output,  and provide the link in a comment.

Comment: Thanks for the response. Yes, it still fails, here’s the command and the output: https://pastebin.com/raw/1KcMNgzj It seems, that when the number of seconds exceeds ~200, muxing overhead happens. Also both shots taken are completely blank, i.e. filled with white pixels. The frame on 00:00:00 should be white, but the 200.000 s one shouldn’t. I’ve put a one-by-one command and the file sizes they produced for comparison.

Comment: @tijagi I haven't been able to look into this in more detail yet, so instead of the select filter I recommend using `-ss` as you were in your second command. If you prefer you can do it all in one command as shown [here](https://superuser.com/a/1018651), and the process *may* be somewhat faster.

Comment: Already done the lazy way, thanks!